# Theme layout for home page

Tags: theme-development

I'd like to create a theme with this layout for the homepage.

[image]

At the moment I am working off an already existing html website I am a confused about what the white and green/blue part of the layout should be named, i.e. what file name it should have.

Thus far I have the bottom footer and the light blue background set up, but am at a lost for what the body file should be (to get it centred with the white background).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a **WordPress-specific** question. It sounds like an HTML/CSS question. Note: WordPress doesn't really care how you define your HTML/CSS markup.

Comment: What are your *theme-development* references? Are you studying how to structure a theme?

Comment: I've reviewed the Codex (which I obviously need to review again) and I am using a book called Professional WordPress. Would you have any advice on other reference items/tools that can be used? Thank you very much.

Comment: [Search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development) this Stack as there are plenty of nice Q&A's. I'd suggest you to reframe the Question (or open a new altogether) asking specifics that you're not understanding. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @brasofilo You can add a tag link with using `[tag:theme-development]`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the tips guys! (Also, sorry my question wasn't very clear)

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that this question is WordPress-related, here's what you need to know:

Start with a file named `index.php`.

Give that file the following markup:

```
<?php

get_header();

get_template_part( 'loop' );

get_sidebar();

get_footer();

?>
```

- The [**`get_header()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) template tag will include a file named `header.php`.
- The [**`get_template_part( 'loop' )`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) template tag will include a file named `loop.php`
- The [**`get_sidebar()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) template tag will include a file named `sidebar.php`
- The [**`get_footer()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) template tag will include a file named `footer.php`

What you put inside those template-part files is entirely up to you.

For more detailed information, refer to the Codex:

- [Stepping Into Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates)
- [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. Your answer was what I was looking for. (I apologize for phrasing it very poorly - I meant to ask about what the file name should be. I am new to WordPress and even after reading the Codex several times am still a bit confused.) Thanks very much.

Comment: No worries. I would recommend reading/understanding the **Stepping Into Templates** Codex entry, as that should answer *most* of your questions.

Comment: I hadn't gone over Stepping Into Templates but I did review Theme Development. I will be sure to re-read (and try my best) to understand everything. Thanks very much again.